# When applying for a USA B2 visa, do I need to declare previous UK visa cancellations?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-cancellation

I'm working in the UK (holding a UK permanent visa) and planning to travel to the US for a conference.

I would like to bring my wife and we will stay in the US for 7 days in total, so I'll need to apply for a B1/B2 visa and my wife needs a B2 visa.

My wife had her UK visa cancelled before, then we got married and reapplied. She now has a UK dependent visa and works in the UK as a software developer.

- [After my girlfriend's visa being cancelled at UK border, will her UK visa application be banned?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74772/after-my-girlfriends-visa-being-cancelled-at-uk-border-will-her-uk-visa-applic) (Cancellation record)
- https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/after-my-girlfriends-visa-being-cancelled-at-uk-border-can-i-get-her-a-depende (Applied dependent visa)

---

According to this page
https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/required-documents/

> **If you have ever been arrested, cautioned, convicted** you are required
>   to declare it, even if it is considered spent and furnish a police
>   certificate known as an ACRO.  The Rehabilitation of Offenders Act
>   does not apply to U.S. visa law.

And this page explains more about the related documentation, but we are not sure if they are applicable to my wife's visa application. https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/ineligibilities-and-waivers-2/arrest-caution-conviction/

- ACPO Criminal Records Office (ACRO)
- Personal data form VCU1 (PDF) https://photos.state.gov/libraries/unitedkingdom/164203/cons-visa/VCU01_London.pdf - (It only asks for US visa refusal history - section 4 and 5)

I'm also not sure if any of the **Security and Background Information** questions from DS-160 is relevant. e.g.:

[image: Security Background Information]

---

**Questions:**

1. Does she need to declare her previous UK visa cancellation when
   applying for her US B2 visa? In what format (any form to fill)? I can't find any relevant section in **DS-160** (https://ceac.state.gov/GenNIV/default.aspx) either.
2. Does she need to get an [ACRO police certificate](https://www.acro.police.uk/police_certificates.aspx)?
3. Would it affect my B1/B2 visa application? (We plan to write a cover letter for each of our applications saying that we will travel together and stay in the same hotel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, unless specifically asked at the interview.
2. No
3. Unlikely in my opinion. It depends on whether or not the counselor knows about the cancellation, why it was cancelled, and how that affects your credibility and intentions as a non-immigrant to the USA. I wouldn't bother with a covering letter because if there is an issue, you will have the opportunity to clarify face-to-face. The counselor won't look at your covering letter.

Unless your wife was arrested, the answers to all the questions above should be no. You don't need to volunteer any information that they are not asking you for.

You should fill out the DS-160 accurately, and answer any questions that you are asked at the interview.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply. When we are asked at the interview about previous visa rejection in another country, do we need to prepare any documentation along with our explanation? (e.g. the previous removal letter)

Comment: @Max it can't hurt to carry it with you but I doubt they'll ask to see the letter. The American visa process isn't really based on documentation.

Comment: Much appreciated. I'll update this post after the interview to reflect the situation.