# UK Visa refusal.. what do I do?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I applied to go on a 2 week vacation from work last month to the UK, But I was denied a visa. Note that I schooled in the UK (Masters) from 2015-2016, and was back in the UK in 2017 twice on seperate visit visas (sponsored by my dad). The last time in 2017, I had a six month visa, and applied to spend 2 weeks, instead I spent 107 days, by choice. This was a joint decision between parents and I as I was to resume for my phd in 4 months, so i needed to house-hunt and do some research and keep myself busy.. Note that I was not working or accessing public funds, rather my Dad had money sent to me each month( I have bank statements to prove).. my visa was application was refused last month, citing paragraphs v.2a and e. One of the reasons they gave was that the money in my accnt wasnt from my Dad’s account. They also brought up my last visit and hw I stayed 107 days instead of 2 weeks like I applied to. Note that my accnt was well furnished as my dad (my sponsor) directed a business payment into my accnt (More than sufficient).. i resume a Phd programme in october, I have already paid my fees, I only deffered it from march to october for personal reasons. more so, my Girlfriend (Ghanian) sent me an invite for her graduation for July. Do i stand a chance? How do i go about it? I am Nigerian by the way.

Comment: Your chances do not look positive. You stated you would stay 2 weeks previously but stayed 107 days - that’s a material change which makes your intention to leave after the stated 2 weeks this time not credible. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry. You’ll get a better answer if you upload a copy of your refusal letter with personal details blacked out.

Comment: I do not have a copy of my refusal letter, as I gave it to my Dad. But, I remember accurately the content of the letter. It stated, “you were issued a visa to the UK previously, most recently on the 23/10/17, where you stated you would spend only 14 days, but went to on stay 107 days, Now we do not know why you decided to stay longer than 14 days, but the way you were maintained and your source of funds are unknown. This casts a bit of doubt on your application”.. they further went on to say the money in my account, although sufficient doesnt appear to come from my dad’s account..

Comment: I can prove I was receiving money from home as my Nigerian bank account was active, and funded monthly, and I have my bank statement to show. I just needed some time off cos of some family issues I was having, and to do some research, as I had only 4 months before I resumed my PhD.

Comment: Even though you can prove you were receiving money from home, that doesn't disprove that you were working in the UK. Give up on going on a vacation, and find a lawyer specialising in UK immigration to help you maybe get a permit to enter the UK for your Phd studies (that will probably take some time, so get started on it).

Answer (score 5):

I can't identify the paragraphs you say you were refused under, but I suspect you actually mean Appendix V Para 4.2(a) and (e), which require you to establish that you will leave at the end of your visit, and that you have enough funds.

The ECO hasn't said it in so many words, but he believes you were working illegally during your 107 day visit. This is a serious problem for you to overcome if you're going to get a visitor visa any time soon.

If you are to apply again you will need to explain exactly what you were doing for 107 days and why, and provide supporting documentation if at all possible.

You will also need to document exactly where and how you obtained the funds for that trip, and for the trip you propose to make this year. You should include any and all bank statements that are pertinent.

It's not clear from your post whether the ECO is aware that you intend to return to study in October. Assuming that he is, you will need to come up with some convincing reason why you will return to Nigeria in July, only to return in October, a period not dissimilar in length to the 107 days.

You should be aware that a second refusal could adversely affect any future visa applications, including the study visa you will need in October. Consider whether your girlfriend's graduation is worth the possible risk to your studies.

Comment: Yes, The ECO is aware.. as I added my tuition receipts to my last application as part of my proposed activities was to see my supervisor in person and discuss my deferment.. about documenting my source of funding, I have my bank statements showing transfers from my Dad’s account, and the rest. i guess I’ll just stay back and not attend my girlfriend’s graduation, as she wants me to come in june, so I can help her prepare and shop, and pack her stuff after grad.. and we return to Ghana together..  I am really scared and hope it doesny affect my PhD. Thank you all for your time !!

Comment: I need to know please, during my next application in october for a student Visa, do I still address the “107 days” issue  or I can just go ahead and apply normally.. could this cost me my visa in october, yet again??

Comment: @Wisham You are right to be scared. The very significant overstay is going to cause you a lot of trouble in your student visa application. If you want more specific advice, you must post the text of your refusal letter.

Comment: @Wisham As stated in the answer from InsanityRules, you will have to clarify the reason for your lengthy stay, what you did during this time and how you supported yourself. One refusal on your record already isn’t good for future prospects so I echo Henrik’s advice about employing an immigration lawyer.