# After a 6 month tourist visa can I come back to the UK on a fiance visa in order to get married the same year

Tags: visas, uk, repeat-visits

I have been in the UK for 4 months and want to go back for another month within the 6 months of my multiple entry visitor visa.

I am now also in the process of completing my fiancé visa as well. The plan is that I will return later in the year to get married.

I just wanted to check if this was allowed as overall I will be in the UK for longer than 6 months this year, albeit that it will be on two visas - a visitor visa and a fiancé visa. Is this allowed?

Comment: Theres no limit on how long you can be in the UK in a year, you could come for 6 months leave and come back the next day if the immigration officer allowed it. As you are applying for an immigrant visa they wont use how long you've spent in the UK against you, you and your partner just need to fit the requirements.

Comment: for the fiance visa you also have to send your passport to the UK so you wouldnt be able to travel while its processing this can take months from personal experience.

Comment: Thank you, that's really useful - the passport aspect is fine, as my fiancé will return to Thailand prior to the application being made. (Apologies, it is her that has been over for 4 months already rather than me). I just wanted to make sure we weren't going to run into problems with her being here for longer than 6 months within the year, as on the Gov website it states "You can stay in the UK for up to 6 months with a General Visitor visa" . I thought as the fiancé visa is a different visa it may not matter, but thought it was worth checking. Thanks again

Comment: Its 6 months at a time, obviously if you seem to be spending a lot of time in the UK the immigration officers wont be happy if its seen you're living in the UK. Theres no official rule but generally you should spend more time in your home country than the UK in 12 months or you're seen to be trying to live in the UK. This will only be a problem coming in on a visitor visa lots of times.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Good to know. I guess the fact that the second visa is a fiancé one, should out paid to their worries about that anyway, as she will be making the UK her home after the marriage anyway :)

Comment: @Pete What was the original Visit period stated in the Visit visa application? There are questions on this site from people who’ve fallen foul of assuming that the standard 6 months’ entry allows a much longer stay than first stated https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry It might be important to adhere to the original basis in order not to jeopardise the fiancée visa application

Answer (score 1):

The UK does not have a rule on how long one could spend in the country during a given time period. At the border, officials may look at frequent, repeated, or regular visits and consider whether they coincide with visa- or visa-free-entry conditions. Your stay was to to maintain your relationship, very much in line with your intended marriage and your return with an appropriate visa.