# My Marriage visitor visa is rejected. Is it wise to apply again but for the tourist visitor visa instead?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

Me and my girlfriend are both non-EU. She is a student in the UK with her studies completing at the end of this year and I am a full time employee at a top company in Germany with a German Permanent residence (in Germany since 6 years already so already very near to my citizenship rights in Germany)

Along with my supporting documentation, its proven that my salary is 3455€/month (after tax) and along with the 6 month salary slips. No clue how the officer got that number wrong there. Actually it would be around 3700€/month (after tax) if I include the two bonuses (June and December) per year, that too reflected in one of the salary slips with pay of 5200€/June (after tax).

Overall (~38K-41K Pounds)/year after tax. In my opinion this is good enough salary on the UK scale too, right ?

Further, a bank balance statement of ~80000 €. Not at all sure how did the visa officer evaluate my insufficient funds?

Given the above points, I don't understand at all

1. how the officer concludes of my intention of NOT going back to Germany and staying in the UK
2. my intention to use the public funds for the expenses?

Given the high bureaucracy, I no longer intend to marry in the UK anymore but in my home country instead.

Is it wise to go for the visitor tourist visa instead as I just want to meet my girlfriend? Is it risky that although with my strong intention to come back to Germany given the entirely favorable circumstances, the officer might simply reject the second application based on the first? Although, logically we both are non EU knowing there is no chance of me claiming UK citizenship too on my fiancees behalf?

PS: I had 5 short stay entries in UK in the last one year alone (entries less than one week) which is also a proof of my intention not to STAY LONGER periods or permanently in UK.

Any answers/experiences would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

[image: Resual Reply]

Comment: Five short stay entries could also indicate building up ties in the UK and/or looking for work. The ECO is questioning whether the relationship is genuine, what evidence did you submit? If you apply for a standard visitor visa straightaway, the ECO may assume you intend to follow through on your original plan to marry.

Comment: Welcome new user.  Couldn't you just meet in Germany?  The food is incredibly better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Concerning relationship is genuine or not, I submitted the following

1) I have submitted the 'No marriage Certificate' for single status proof from my Home Country. This is an oath certificate that is attested from Foreign ministry to indicate no proveious marriage.
2) Some conversation emails with the Marriage halls in London

What else could I have given for relationship?

--> With the current proof of my income and permanent residence status and my citizenship rights right above my head,does my application still seem fishy that I might be trying to settle in UK?

Comment: @Fattie She is a student, she needs a visa for Schengen area. Usually the visa is for few days and max 3 months. In my case, I get a 6 months visitor visa multiple entries. 
Secondly, I am planning for apply for her Family reunion visa to Germany for which we need a marriage certificate.

Comment: @Hassan The single status certificate doesn’t evidence an ongoing relationship. You could provide eg photos going back to when you met; evidence of trips outside UK taken together;  visits to you in Germany by your fiancée; record of contact with her such as SMS, emails.

Comment: @Hassan UK standard visitor visas are typically multiple entry and valid for 6 months. That doesn’t necessarily mean it’s wise to use one to visit regularly (or to change the intended length of stay, come to that) if that visit pattern does not jive with what you stated in the application. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry

Comment: Yes, I agree. The lack of proof for a genuine relationship might be missing in my case. Stupid me :O

Comment: This is another classic case of UK ECO gone rogue & delusional. A man who makes €41,000 in Germany and an €80,000 bank balance cannot afford a wedding without accessing public funds? Sheer madness. And you will make the UK your home? Like really? Do they walk on gold paved streets in the UK?

Answer (score 6):

The rejection letter indicates that the visa officer has no problem with your financial status. The rejection was not for that reason.

Instead the officer does not consider you have provided enough evidence that you actually do intend to marry the person you indicate, or that the marriage will be a genuine one (meaning one not conducted purely for the purposes of immigrating). Note that even if he believed you would return to Germany after your visit, he would be obliged to refuse your visa if he believed you either were not going to marry, or were entering into a sham marriage.

The specifics mentioned are:

- You have not made the preparations for the wedding, such as booking a registry office or other venue.
- You have not indicated why you want to marry in the UK, rather than in Germany where you live, or in the home country of you or your fiance.
- You have not given evidence that your relationship is genuine. A certificate of singleness is of no use (many people are single, yet do not want to marry). Things that might be used to indicate a genuine relationship include: timeline of your relationship, such as where you met and what you have done together (backed up by evidence); evidence of travel to visit each other on a frequent basis; evidence of visits to each others families; photographs of you together; copies of communication between you over the period of your relationship.

To answer your actual question, a tourist visa will not allow you to get married.  A wedding official will need to see your marriage visa before they will marry you. If you wish to abandon your plans to marry your fiance in Britain, and instead merely visit her, it's hard to say if that will be successful. In your favour is your track record of visits and the stability of your situation, together with the fact that the genuineness of your relationship is not a factor in a visitor visa. Against you is a visa rejection. My guess is that you would be granted one, but it's just a guess.

Comment: `Instead the officer does not consider you have provided enough evidence that you actually do intend to marry the person you indicate, or that the marriage will be a genuine one` No immigrant I know in his right mind with a decent salary in Germany and close to citizenship would want to get into a sham marriage to stay in the UK. The UK ain't all that.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen From the officer's point of view the marriage may be for the benefit of the fiance, not the OP. That's what I meant in the second paragraph.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen The fiance is in the UK on a student visa, not a British citizen, which seems to add weight to DJClayworth's point.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It still is not plausible. An immigrant man in Germany will travel to UK to marry a foreign student in a sham marriage for what? To get her to Germany? It makes no sense whatsoever to me. None. She could not go to Germany or her home country for said sham marriage?

Comment: I do agree that enough evidence was not provided as a proof for my relationship bt 'I am not satisfied that you are able to cover all reasonable costs in relation 2 your visit widout working or seeking public funds'. Means a normal avg. marriage in UK costs more than 80K €s ? a Joke? A foreigner with a much higher avg. salary than in UK and one of the strongest employment retainment laws in Germany, OP 'concluded that I might settle in the UK'? wow
I completely agree -proof of relationship was not strong but seems like in the end, they just wanted 2 make their point stronger by whatever means

Comment: @DJClayworth
We are now planning as follows:
1) We plan to travel to home country in one month in december to get married there
Then I aplpy for my tourist visitor visa along with my marraige certificate from my home country. Does this make my point stronger as this would remove the main point of concern for OP's last rejection? OR

Would this worsen the application as deliberately mentioning about marraige in visitor tourist visa and point to previous rejection ? 

Thank you

Comment: Your proposal is perfect. Of course if you get another incompetent ECO, he could also still insist that you are now even more motivated to settle with your wife in the UK as an illegal immigrant. Your girlfriend graduates in December and I assume leaves UK. Why do you still want to go to the UK so soon?

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen. My girlfriend graduates next year August 2019 and her visa in the UK is only upto Oct 2019. After her graduation, she is supposed to leave anyway.
My primary reason for my visit visa is that so I can visit her from Jan2019 till Aug19 while she completes her degree. Also,I need to visit because I want to help my girlfriend (with traveling, appointment, supporting docs etc.) to apply for her Family Reunion Visa in German Embassy in London. 

I mean if the officer wants 2 reject, they can make up any reason to reject whatsoever as they say 'there are always 2 sides'