# Change in intended date of Arrival . Uk visit visa

Tags: uk, airports, standard-visitor-visas, late-arrival

Can I change my travel plans or intended date of arrival after getting UK visit visa ? Will there be problem at immigration? I mentioned in my application that I want to visit my brother in mid week of March but now I want to delay it for a month .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem if you have changed within 6months time frame. Most importantly they also advise to plans after visa confirmation.plans are plans rather if you stated any specific time bound reason like going to attend birthday, wedding etc.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the date of your trip shouldn’t be a problem providing the new timeframe is within your visa validity - plans change, after all. If you submitted an invitation letter from your brother with your application, you could have him send you an email with the new dates and a reference to why the plan changed, so that you have something to show Immigration in the UK if asked.  Changing the length of your trip could cause you a problem if it’s a significant change eg 2 weeks to 2 months [Cancelled UK visa on entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry)

Comment: The thing is my brother is reaching Pakistan today due to sudden death of my Uncle and he will stay here for whole month and will be back to UK on exact same date I mentioned in my application I.e 8 of March . Now he says you delay for one month so that he could avail leave when I am there . Confusing. And definitely I don’t want to extend my intended one week stay, I just want to postpone the same one week for next month