# I want to postpone travel to the UK, can I postpone the date of my visa interview instead of cancelling my application and reapplying later?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, itineraries

I am really having problems getting advice so maybe you can help.

My wife and I are visiting my daughter in the UK for 3 weeks. My application has been submitted to TLSconect today (9/3/20) and my application shows my intended departure from Johannesburg, South Africa on 12/3/20.

I want to change the departure date to about mid July. I can cancel my application and reapply later, but would rather not and try another route.

If I can extend my interview by 60 days then I will have another 3 months which will work date-wise but now my intended departure (12/4/20) is way out.

What do you suggest?

Comment: In the US, numeric dates are written month/day/year, but in the UK and many other countries the more logical day/month/year. I suggest using month names, not numbers, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Melvin How long are you intending to stay in the UK? You are not tied to the date of entry given in the application, and standard visitor visas are almost always valid for a 6 month period from the date of issue. In any event, a departure date of 12 March isn’t going to be feasible for an application submitted on 9th. You can probably change your biometric appointment date but you can’t ask for a departure date more than 3 months ahead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change in intended date of Arrival . Uk visit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131702/change-in-intended-date-of-arrival-uk-visit-visa)