# Can I change my travel date earlier from what I put in my application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, itineraries

I just got my UK Standard Visitor visa, valid March 14-Sep14 2019. In my application, I intended to travel on May 23 - June 5, 2019. Can I still change my travel dates to earlier dates than my application?

Comment: Visa for where? And what are the visa validity dates?

Comment: Its UK standard visitor visa. I just got my visa today valid from march 14, 2019 til Sept 14, 2019. Can i still change my travel date from what i put during my application?

Answer (score 2):

Travel plans change all the time. You are good to travel anytime on or after 14 March, providing you exit on or before 15 September. Just a note of caution against extending your stay significantly beyond the length of time originally stated in your application [Cancelled UK visa on entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry)

Comment: This is such a big help. Thank you so much for answering my question 