# 6 months visitors' visa validity...as the dates on the visa, or from the date of entry into the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens, visa-expiration

Our relatives in the Philippines have just been given their visitors' visas for coming to the UK, but the starting date is given (on the visas) as 27th March, rather than  29th April as given by them on their application forms.  Expiry of the visas is therefore given as 27th September.  Can they nevertheless stay for 6 months from their entry date, or do they have to leave within the dates given on their visas?  They potentially lose a month at least...

Comment: Did they state they’d be staying for 6 months in their application? A material change in the stated length of stay can lead to denial of entry https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry or problems with a subsequent visa application

Comment: The point that @Traveller makes is very important. If your parents applied for a visa saying "We're going to stay for a couple of weeks" and show up at the border saying "We're here for six months", there's a good chance that they'll not be allowed to enter the UK and will be accused of lying on their visa form.

Comment: Check very, very carefully whether they are actually allowed to stay six months. Usually you would get a visa that allows you to stay say four weeks, any time from March to September. If you have multiple entries, you could stay two weeks, leave, come back for another two weeks, again from March to September. I'd say it is very unlikely they are allowed to stay March to September.

Comment: @gnasher729 UK visitor visas don’t work quite like that. They are almost always issued as multiple entry with a validity period of 6 months. There is no fixed rule on the length of/number of visits during the validity period. What matters is whether the holder satisfies Border officials regarding V4.2 of the Immigration Rules under ‘Genuine intention to visit’ https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules